# Neo4j : Metric for label propagation algorithm (LPA)

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm

I ran label propagation algorithm on my data and I would like to know if there is a metric I can use to evaluate the model.

Is there a metric for this algorithm ? If no what can I do to evaluate this algorithm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite unclear and ambiguous question. You can look at the results of the algorithm to evaluate it.